# Selecionar, por quantidade, itens que correspondam a condições

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com uma dúvida na hora de montar uma query.

Vou montar um cenário fictício para demonstrar.

Tenho a tabela `quantidadeQuestoes` com os campos:

- cod_nivel
- cod_categoria
- cod_dificuldade
- quantidade

E tenho a tabela `questoes` com os campos:

- cod_nivel
- cod_categoria
- cod_dificuldade
- descricao

Minha dúvida é. Como pegar da tabela `questoes` a quantidade especificada no campo `quantidade` da tabela `quantidadeQuestoes` onde os outros campos sejam correspondidos.

Com a minha query atual eu estou pegando todos os itens e não apenas a quantidade especificada no campo quantidade, que é o que preciso:

```
SELECT
    qt.descricao
FROM
    quantidadeQuestoes qq
INNER JOIN
    questoes qt ON
    qq.cod_nivel = qt.cod_nivel AND
    qq.cod_categoria = qt.cod_categoria AND
    qq.cod_dificuldade = qt.cod_dificuldade
```

É para eu montar uma prova que contenha tantas questões de um nivel + categoria + dificuldade.

Comment: JoaoPaulo, a tabela quantidadeQuestoes armazena quantos questões existem para a chave (cod_nivel, cod_categoria e cod_dificuldade)?

Comment: Não lembro se é possível essa syntax, mas já tentou colocar um `top qq.quantidade` na query?

Comment: @cantoni não entendi sua pergunta.

Comment: Não descobri em que parte da query caberia esse top @LuisHenrique. Onde tentei o SQL não permitiu

Comment: Minha dúvida está em relação ao seu modelo. Estou entendendo que a tabela quantidadeQuestoes armazena a quantidade de questões para o mesmo cod_nivel, cod_categoria e cod_dificuldade. Já a tabela questoes armazena as questões propriamente ditas. Entendi certo?

Comment: Exatamente @cantoni.

Comment: Certo, vou postar uma resposta aqui. De qualquer maneira, pelo modelo postado, não estou vendo razão para a existência da tabela quantidadeQuestoes. Na resposta explico.

Comment: Se a tabela quantidadeQuestoes armazena simplesmente o maximo de registros de questoes da outra tabela não entendi o que você quer. O que eu tinha entendido é que para criar uma prova cria-se registros na tabela quantidadeQuestoes expecificando o nivel, categoria e dificuldade e o número de questões desejadas.

Comment: Você entendeu certo @LuisHenrique. O número de questões já está pre-definido. A partir dele eu monto uma prova com a quantidade de questões especificadas com nivel +  categoria + dificuldade

Comment: Você tentou fazer `select top qq.quantidade qt.descricao from...`? De qualquer maneira isso sempre pegaria as mesma questões (as N primeiras baseado nos outros filtros), acho que o sistema para capturar as questões e gerar as provas poderia ser reformulado e não tratado no banco de dados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você vai precisar de uma subquery. Consegui uma solução usando o [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), que numera as linhas encontradas. O `PARTITION BY` está sendo usado para zerar a contagem para cada linha da tabela `quantidadeQuestoes`. Ficou assim:

```
SELECT descricao
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY q.cod_nivel, q.cod_categoria, q.cod_dificuldade ORDER BY q.cod_nivel DESC) AS num,
    q.[cod_nivel], 
    q.[cod_categoria], 
    q.[cod_dificuldade], 
    q.[descricao],
    qq.[quantidade]
  FROM questoes q
    INNER JOIN quantidadeQuestoes qq
    ON qq.cod_nivel = q.cod_nivel AND
    qq.cod_categoria = q.cod_categoria AND
    qq.cod_dificuldade = q.cod_dificuldade 
) sq
WHERE sq.num <= sq.quantidade
```

Veja [demo no sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72105/10).

Comment: Removi a minha resposta, ela estava errada. Além disso, essa reposta ficou muito elegante. ROW_NUMBER e PARTITION já me salvaram várias vezes.

Comment: @bfavaretto, não entendi essa clausula where sq.num <= sq.quantidade, qual a lógica dessa condição?

Comment: A lógica é garantir que o número de registros retornados por chave ( cod_nivel, cod_categoria e cod_dificuldade) seja menor que a quantidade. Se não fizer isso, vão vir mais registros do que você deseja. A query, no final, garante que você sempre selecionará X registro da tabela QUESTOES, onde X é o campo quantidade.

Comment: Exatamente, o @cantoni foi mais rápido que eu :) Experimente rodar só a query de dentro que você vai entender.

Comment: Para entender, execute a query de dentro e veja como o campo num é gerado. Quando vc fizer isso, entenderá a razão do (sq.num <= sq.quantidade)

Comment: Puxa, estamos sincronizados @bfavaretto. :-)